# Approximating the moment of inertia of a quadcopter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I want to compute an approximated moment of inertia for my quadcopter: my idea is to take the frame and the electronics, approximate it as a sphere in the center of mass $M$ and radius $R$ (with moment $\frac{2}{5}MR^2$), approximate the motors as 4 cylinders (of mass $m$ and radius $r$) with moment

$$I_x = I_y = \frac{1}{12}m(3r^2 + h^2)$$

and $I_z = \frac{1}{2}mr^2$, and use Huygens–Steiner to move the reference axis of the cylinders towards the sphere (fixing a 'compound' reference system in the center of mass of the sphere).

I get
$$I_x = I_y = \frac{2}{5}MR^2 + (\frac{1}{12}m(3r^2 + h^2) + ml^2)*2$$

$$I_z = \frac{2}{5}MR^2 + (\frac{1}{2}mr^2 + ml^2)*4$$

where $h$ is the height of each cylinder and $d$ the horizontal distance between a cylinder and the sphere. Are my computations correct?

Comment: I think a sphere is a terrible model to use - probably a collection of rods would be better. Because these things go with distance squared, a small error makes a big difference. Solid sphere: $\frac25 m r^2$, hollow sphere: $\frac23 m r^2$ - a more than 50% difference. How close are you trying to get?

Comment: This is not a problem, it is only an exercise. Maybe I'm not explained well, I was only asking whether my computations are right or not, thanks @Floris

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [check-my-work question are off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583).

Answer (score 1):

A quad rotor UAV has a very complex geometry. Unless you have an assembly drawing in CAD, you are better off measuring the moment of inertias directly by creating a torsional pendulum. Using a balancing scheme, figure out where the center of gravity (mass) is. Suspend the copter through that center and on the axis you wish to measure with a known torsional spring. Allow it to freely oscillate and measure the natural frequency. Calculate the moment of inertia as $$I = {k \over{\omega^2}}$$

Comment: Yes I know that it is a better method, but I have to do it with it using well-known moment of inertia as stated in my question, as exercise. Can you tell my if my computation are right? thanks